# Persisting select option on page refresh React Remix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, remix.run

I have a select with 2 options (*en, no*), which switches the language onChange.

I store selected language to `localStorage`. Because I'm using [Remix](https://remix.run) I cannot simply access localStorage, because of the server-side rendering, so I'm using:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const localLanguage = localStorage.getItem('language');
}
```

**Select** component:

```
<select
  name="language"
  id="language-select"
  defaultValue={language}
  onChange={e => changeLanguageHandler(e.target.value)}
>
  <option value="no" label="NO">
    Norwegian
  </option>
  <option value="en" label="EN">
    English
  </option>
</select>
```

**Translation** function:

```
export function useLocalTranslation() {
  const [language, setLanguage] = React.useState(() => {
     // react lazy initial state 
     // ( i think i should be using lazy initial state, because of the serverside rendering
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const initialState = localStorage.getItem('language') ?? 'no';
      return initialState;
    }
  });
  const no = useNoTranslations();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const savedLanguage = localStorage.getItem('language');
    if (savedLanguage) {
      setLanguage(savedLanguage);
    }
  }, []);

  const t = React.useCallback(
    (key: TKey) => {
      if (key === '0') return '0';

      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        const currentLanguage = localStorage.getItem('language');

        if (currentLanguage === 'no') {
          // console.log(currentLanguage);
          return no?.[key as string] ?? en[key as TranslationsKeys] ?? key;
        }
        // console.log(currentLanguage);
      }
      return en[key as TranslationsKeys] ?? key;
    },
    [no],
  );

  function changeLanguageHandler(lang: string) {
    setLanguage(lang);
    localStorage.setItem('language', lang);
  }

  return { t, language, changeLanguageHandler };
}
```

My goal is to have selected option saved and persistent on page refresh, now when I refresh the page, it gets reseted to NO (*Norwegian*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can solve this by giving value attribute instead of defaultValue.

Comment: Cannot believe how simple yet correct is this, thanks!

Comment: this is because of controlled/uncontrolled components concept.